# Graph the average line using sns lineplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id|date    |amount
1 |02-04-18|3000
1 |05-04-19|5000
1 |10-04-19|2600
2 |10-04-19|2600
2 |11-04-19|3000
```

I want to the amount spent over time for each unique id and have an average trend line. This is the code that I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

temp_m = df.pivot_table(index='id',columns='id',values='amount', fill_value=0)
temp_m = pd.melt(temp, id_vars=['id'])
temp_m['date'] = temp_m['date'].astype('str')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
for i, group in temp_m.groupby('id'):
    group.plot('id', y='amount', ax=ax,legend=None)
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
```

[image]

Each line is a unique customer.

Goal: I want to add another line that is the average of all the individual customer trends.

Also if there is a better way to graph the individual lines as well please let me know

Comment: What is temp in your code above?

Comment: @NYC Coder Its the original dataframe pivoted and stored as temp

Answer (score 0):

At first we reshape the data

```
agg = df.set_index(['date', 'id']).unstack()
agg.columns = agg.columns.get_level_values(-1)
```

This makes plotting very easy:

`sns.lineplot(data=agg)`

The average trends can be calculated by

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regress = {}
idx = agg.index.to_julian_date()[:, None]
for c in agg.columns:
    regress[c] = LinearRegression().fit(idx, agg[c].fillna(0)).predict(idx)

trend = pd.Series(pd.DataFrame(regress).mean(axis=1).values, agg.index)
```

Comment: I get the following error when running this : ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: @dsmess: Could you please provide some more sample data? Maybe we need one more aggregation step.